# Dart, Map / dictionary with classes and functions not working

Tags: dart

I have a Map / dictionary made of classes and functions and it is not working for some reason. Here is my code:

```
class MalInt {
  final int value;

  MalInt(this.value);
}

class MalSymbol {
  final String value;

  MalSymbol(this.value);
}

Map<MalSymbol, Function> repl_env = <MalSymbol, Function>{
  MalSymbol('+'): (MalInt a, MalInt b) => new MalInt(a.value + b.value),
  MalSymbol('-'): (MalInt a, MalInt b) => new MalInt(a.value - b.value),
  MalSymbol('*'): (MalInt a, MalInt b) => new MalInt(a.value * b.value),
  MalSymbol('/'): (MalInt a, MalInt b) => new MalInt(a.value ~/ b.value),
};

Map<String, int> fruits = <String, int>{"apple": 1, "banana": 2};

main() {
  var symbol = new MalSymbol("+");
  print(repl_env[symbol]);
  print(fruits["banana"]);
}
```

The output is:

```
null
2
```

So, my fruits Map is working. But my `<MalSymbol, Function>` Map is not working and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to override the method `operator` in your `MalSymbol`, so your code will look like this:

```
class MalInt {
  final int value;

  MalInt(this.value);
}

class MalSymbol {
  final String value;

  MalSymbol(this.value);
  
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    identical(this, other) ||
    other is MalSymbol &&
    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
    value == other.value;
  
  @override
  int get hashCode => value.hashCode;
}

Map<MalSymbol, Function> repl_env = <MalSymbol, Function>{
  MalSymbol('+'): (MalInt a, MalInt b) => new MalInt(a.value + b.value),
  MalSymbol('-'): (MalInt a, MalInt b) => new MalInt(a.value - b.value),
  MalSymbol('*'): (MalInt a, MalInt b) => new MalInt(a.value * b.value),
  MalSymbol('/'): (MalInt a, MalInt b) => new MalInt(a.value ~/ b.value),
};

Map<String, int> fruits = <String, int>{"apple": 1, "banana": 2};

main() {
  var symbol = new MalSymbol("+");
  print(repl_env[symbol]);
  print(fruits["banana"]);
}
```